# Как разместить видео с YouTube на страницу с помощью тега video? HTML

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Есть задача вывести видео с YouTube на страницу с помощью тега video. Вот как это выглядело в моей голове:

```
<body>

    <video controls>
        <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9IGiYQFbfw">
    </video>

</body>
```

И вроде получилось, даже кнопки управления видео есть, но видео не появляется. См. картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто меня интересует вывод видео с YouTube именно с помощью этого метода, а не с помощью официального метода вставки на HTML страницу предусмотренную Google. Мой вариант имеет шанс на жизнь, или только оф. способ работает? Как я могу расположить видео с YouTube на мою страницу?

Comment: Ваш вариант не имеет шанса на жизнь.

Comment: Мне кажется, легче просто скачать видео, если так хотите

Answer (score -1):

```html
<video controls>
    <source src="https://r5---sn-hxb54vo-gv8l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1589131921&ei=Mea3Xr2LG4ubigSWqYiAAw&ip=120.51.212.207&id=o-AOLx8Nr9p5YH91zPIFdHzkjm_zxjV7E8itlmQqHtJkUe&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=28516089&ratebypass=yes&dur=463.354&lmt=1577943492145459&fvip=5&c=WEB&txp=5531432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIhAM1NOSHX14mzQr0UGe6goikoNKujJSu7ahTv2hkuk6TmAiBN9rm3eO6vOkq158rzLLag4QgogqCV5Ffigfd34qdjQg%3D%3D&video_id=h9IGiYQFbfw&title=%D0%AF+%D0%A0%D0%96%D0%90%D0%9B+%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B+%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%90+-+%D0%A1%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A8%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95+%D0%96%D0%98%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95+%2C+%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%AB+%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%98+%D0%9B%D0%A3%D0%A7%D0%A8%D0%98%D0%95+%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%AB&redirect_counter=1&rm=sn-ogurz76&req_id=5dfa4da503d5a3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mh=1e&mip=81.177.186.118&mm=31&mn=sn-hxb54vo-gv8l&ms=au&mt=1589121947&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=24&lsparams=ipbypass,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgf2bK8oulZiL-fVd-yd80spxp3vnHGX8whec9LyQnhb8CIQDmbE_V3gl8bC4TB-QLvH7hNGqtsqPUmyJjV9sc-kF9NA%3D%3D">
</video>
```

Comment: ссылка сдохнет .....

Answer (score -1):

```
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tTn36NWCpMI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Та ссылка в примере не работает, поэтому я взял другую